# Why do the sign conventions in cartesian geometry work the way they do?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

Usually in a Cartesian form of derivation in math and physics, I have seen that a particular formula is derived for simplicity by taking concerned points say in the first quadrant. Few examples are the derivation of mirror formula, lens formula, lens maker formula, distance between two points. Later, they extend the formula to all cases and say : "The formula is valid for all cases independent of quadrant and position because we have taken proper care of signs". For example, see the case of mirror formula derivation in the book (especially the pointed last paragraph):

[image: meow]

Similarly here for distance formula in SL loney.

[image]
I do not understand deeply that why do this happen ? I know that it can be proved in the above cases by actually deriving for all cases and observing that it is confirming, but how can we say it generally? So the question is :

**Why do the sign convention in coordinate geometry work the way it does ?**

Comment: At some level of hand-waiving, if some polynomial or analytical function is zero in the first quadrant/octant, then it is zero everywhere. A more exact statement might be above the level that can be assumed in these texts.

Comment: @User0 The Direction of incident ray is in itself a part of sign convention. So the question remains same.

Comment: Yes in a way, but the whole sign convention is derived around the direction of incident ray

Comment: @User0 I understand your feeling and I had too so ( that magnitudes here are irrespective of coordinates). But that's what made me to ask here as it's non-rigorous and still without proof. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: I approve the comment made by Lutz Lehmann. The non-rigorous argumentation of Loney can be inscribed in a general trend in Mathematics : "it works for the first quadrant with positive quantities, then let us try it for the other quadrants ; we just need for that to use negative quantities", alike : "this relationship works for numbers, let us see under which hypotheses it is still true for matrices, etc... ". But you must say to students (this is not done in the given excerpt, and for me it is not honest) : "this is not rigorous ; but it is possible to make it rigorous."

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes. But making it rigorous through considering and proving all cases is quite tedious. That's why I asked for a general proof or deeper meaning. Thanks !

Comment: I didn't say that the rigorous approach was by considering all cases ! Read for example the wonderful book "Géométrie Supérieure" by Michel Chasles (circa 1880 ; I think it has been translated into English), the mathematician who has introduced rigorously signs in geometry (in particular with oriented angles) ; his approach is global.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks. But is the translated version available online (free) ? I have found the french version on internet archive.

Comment: There is indeed an english translation [here](https://www.amazon.com/Trait%C3%A9-G%C3%A9om%C3%A9trie-Superieure-Par-Chasles/dp/1418186066), visibly non free.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks. But unfortunately I can't buy for it now :( I hope I would do so in future. ( Or you can write an answer)